# one liner to generate a random number between 0 and 100 but last digit ends in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Tags: python, random, ansible, jinja2

Without concat strings or `if` conditionals and such, use arithmetics one-liner. Preferably written in Python please.

---

Background of the story: a legacy system requires a listening port last digit ends in [0-4] so [5-9] is reserved for a mirror TCP.

I wrote a deploy script which generates [idempotent random number](https://ansibledaily.com/idempotent-random-number/) but having trouble guarantee the last digit in [0-4]. Since Ansible & Jinja2 template language is limited so I don't want the code relies too much on hairy string operations and `if` conditions.

Once a idempotent random number is generated, I need a arithmetic function to *project* the number to another integer which the last digit is between 0 and 4 and still guarantee the idempotence

Comment: Can you use modulos?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes please!

Comment: Modulus of randon number divided by 4.

Comment: Generate random number from 0 to 49, then flip it around.

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 and 100. Repeat until it ends in 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 (you will need on the average one repetition per number).

Comment: What research have you done? For a 4k rep user, I'm a little surprised that you'd post a question without providing any research or an MCVE.

Comment: @AlexP Will that guarantee the randomness?

Comment: @leaf I am sorry I am bad at arithmetics. Business boilerplate ruined me :( Sometimes I can't come around corners obvious  to you guys.

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @MikeT That will make a random number out of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] but not 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and so on.

Comment: @est I apologize if it came across that way, but I'm not trying to be condescending. Right now, I don't really have any idea how to do this. But every user - even those who have no idea how to solve their problem - are expected to put forth a bit of research.

Comment: @est: Yes. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @est my bad I obviously misread 'In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).' I will return to school immediately.

Comment: @DSM at your convenience please, it's not a major issue, but last digit must end in [0-4]

Comment: Ah, your update mentions idempotence.  Do you have any constraints in that direction?

Comment: @DSM No, just want an easy project function.

Comment: That's not specific enough, because it's the connection which is the hard part.  It's straightforward to generate a random number between 0 and 99 inclusive which ends in 0,1,2,3, or 4, but now your question seems to really be about a mapping from some unspecified set of numbers to the numbers you want.

Comment: @DSM Can you show me the *straightforward* way please? To my  poor understanding, I don't need the mapping to be reversible.

Comment: You want a mapping from [something] to the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,10,11.,,99.  What are the values in _something_?

Comment: @DSM So there are 50 items in `[0,1,2,3,4,10,11...,95]` (The last item should be 95), lets assume *something* to be `range(0, 50)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, if you've randomly selected a number `x` in range(0,50), you can map it to {0,1,2,3,4,10,11,...} like this:

```
y = 10*(x//5) + x % 5
```

For example:

```
In [8]: out = [10 * (x//5) + x % 5 for x in range(50)]

In [9]: out[:10]
Out[9]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

In [10]: out[-10:]
Out[10]: [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]
```

This will turn any number you've generated in the [0,50) range into one satisfying your < 5 mod 10 criterion.

Comment: Are you a wizard? Thanks! Is it possible to further simplify the formula to make the `x` variable appear only once?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with `random.sample` and `mod`:

```
>>> import random
>>> [i for i in random.sample(range(100), 100) if i%10<5]
[24, 23, 62, 90, 80, 12, 4, 30, 43, 92, 21, 33, 41, 63, 52, 44, 81, 61, 31, 70, 73, 20, 0, 74, 2, 84, 11, 53, 13, 42, 50, 64, 60, 32, 71, 34, 72, 51, 1, 22, 91, 94, 40, 14, 82, 93, 3, 83, 54, 10]
```

You can use `next` and a gen. exp to generate a single number:

```
>>> gen = (i for i in random.sample(range(101), 101) if i%10<5) # include 100 in sample
>>> next(gen)
72
>>> next(gen)
84
>>> next(gen)
51
>>> next(gen)
71
>>> next(gen)
34
>>> next(gen)
40
```

Comment: thanks! I edited the question to reflect the background story. Preferably I want some kind of arithmetic function to map to another number directly.

Comment: @est Now, your question is heading towards another new direction

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind disallowing 100, you can simply generate two random numbers, one between 0 and 9, the other between 0 and 4, and combine them arithmetically.

```
port = 10 * random.randint(0,9) + random.randint(0,4)
```

This chooses any of the 50 such ports uniformly.

The simplest way to add 100 to the mix is to simply generate a random number between 0 and 50 (inclusive), and treat one of them as a proxy for 100, with the rest indicating that *another* random number be generated using the scheme above.

```
port = 100 if random.randint(0,50) == 50 else 10 * random.randint(0,9) + random.randint(0,4)
```

Comment: This is why I asked whether we could exclude 100 :-), but it now seems like the OP is generating his own random number over some unspecified range and he wants a mapping from that to his target set.

Comment: @DSM Can we assume I want `[0,1,2,3,4,5,....49]` mapped to `[0,1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,...,95]` please?